# cannot set header node.js error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I know it's caused bu multiple res.json but in this case

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {

  var data = {
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  };
Owner.getUser(data,function(err,response){
    if(err)
        throw err

    if(response){

        console.log(response.password);
        var createHash = function(password){
            return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
        };

        Owner.comparePassword(response.password, createHash(data.password) , function(err, result){

            if(result === true){

             res.json({msg: 1});

            }else{
              res.json({msg: 'Error, Incorrect password!'});
            }
        });

    }else{
        res.json({msg: 'No such account exists! '});
    }
  });
```

How come there's an error saying     `throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');` coz for my logic is ok. each if condition run only one `res.json`.

Comment: Your code doesn't even define `res`. You really should create a [MCVE]

Comment: @Quentin sorry missed that